# searching for a functional interface, without parameter, returning boolean

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

Is there something close to `Callable<Boolean>`, which returns `boolean` not `Boolean`, and throwing no exception?

I'd like to use it like `DoIt.until( ()-> someQueryWithBooleanResult() );`

Yes, I know, `Predicate<Void>` is somewhat similar, but I would not like to use a dummy argument.

Comment: why do you need the primitive ? Autoboxing !

Answer (score 10):

You are looking for [`BooleanSupplier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BooleanSupplier.html).

Generally, any functional interface having no parameters and supplying a value has a name ending with `Supplier`.

As with most types there are variants for `boolean`, `int`, `double`, `long` and generic reference type. But note that there is no `BooleanConsumer`…

Comment: Any specific reasons for the absence of BooleanConsumer?